# Do equals() and == mean the same in Groovy script?

Tags: groovy

The code:

```
    public class Equals {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s1 = new String("java");
        String s2 = new String("java");

        if (s1 == s2) {
            System.out.println("s1 == s2 is TRUE");
        }
        if (s1.equals(s2)) {
            System.out.println("s1.equals(s2) is TRUE");
        }
    }
}
```

As a Java app the output is:

```
s1.equals(s2) is TRUE
```

which is correct, since s1 and s2 actually points to different memory addresses. But in Groovy script as in GroovyConsole, the output is:

```
s1 == s2 is TRUE
s1.equals(s2) is TRUE
```

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sometimes `==` in Groovy calls the `equals` method, but this is not always the case. I'll illustrate by example:

```
class EqualsTest {
    @Override
    boolean equals(Object obj) {
        true
    }
}

assert new EqualsTest() == new EqualsTest()
```

The assertion passes, so the theory appears to stand up. However in the following example the assertion fails

```
class EqualsTest implements Comparable<EqualsTest> {
    @Override
    int compareTo(EqualsTest other) {
        1
    }
    @Override
    boolean equals(Object obj) {
        true
    }
}

assert new EqualsTest() == new EqualsTest() // FAILS!
```

As stated in [Operator Overloading](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operator+Overloading), the test of equality is based on the result of `compareTo` if the class implements `Comparable`, but otherwise it's based on `equals`.

> `a == b` | `a.equals(b) or a.compareTo(b) == 0`
>   The == operator doesn't always exactly match the `.equals()` method. You can think of them as equivalent in most situations. In situations where two objects might be thought "equal" via normal Groovy "coercion" mechanisms, the `==` operator will report them as equal; the `.equals()` method will not do so if doing so would break the normal rules Java has around the equals method.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, these operators are equal. See [operator overloading](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operator+Overloading) in groovy. `==` operator is *transformed* to `equals` method.